# SqlServer DB (2008 compatibility) adds OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY to scripts

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssms, code-generation, compatibility

**Context:**

I have a database running on a modern SqlServer but the database is set to compatibility mode 2008 (100). When I generate out primary keys from this database, the generated script includes `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF` which is a feature introduce much later than 2008. **I expect `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF` to not be included because of the 2008 compatibility mode.**

I can just delete that portion of the generated script but this is a frequent operation and that's a time consuming and error prone work around.

I'm using the right click menu -> script index as -> create to -> new window.

**Questions:**

- Is there a configuration for the server, database, or ssms which would prevent `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF` from appearing when scripting out primary keys?
- Am I wrong to expect 2008 compatibility mode to suppress that feature in generated scripts?

Comment: Have you *actually* tried running the above? Using `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY` works fine in an instance that supports it, regardless of the compatibility setting of the database.

Comment: Ideally, however, I recommend changing that compatibility setting; 2008 has been unsupported for over 2 years, and future versions of SQL Server won't have the compatibility level.

Comment: Are you still using a 2008 instance? I can only assume you must be or this question wouldn't exist. Have you considered upgrading to a supported version of sql server?

Comment: _Am I wrong to expect 2008 compatibility mode_ Yes. And you are also wrong to believe that any code you develop on the newer version will work correctly on the older version as it does on the newer version. You could use SSDT to generate scripts for an older version without this option. Note that you probably should not be using this option generally.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely expected. Your code runs against your SQL Server version, irrespective of compatibility level, and there is no reason for SSMS to generate anything different.

**Your question is based on the false premise that newer T-SQL syntax is protected, or *gated*, from being used under the new compatibility level.**

You seem to be under the assumption that the point of compatibility levels is to ensure *newer* T-SQL code is *backwards* compatible with older versions of SQL Server. **That is simply not the case.**

Compatibility levels ensure **forwards** compatibility for code originally intended for an earlier version, so that it continues to work as expected under the **newer** version of SQL Server. This mainly surrounds preserving optimizer behavior, although some differences in syntax are also preserved (eg `EXCEPT` and `PIVOT` usage in a recursive CTE).

[**This is fully documented:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15#differences-between-compatibility-levels)

> New Transact-SQL syntax is not gated by database compatibility level, except when they can break existing applications by creating a conflict with user Transact-SQL code. These exceptions are documented in the next sections of this article that outline the differences between specific compatibility levels.